# C++ Multiple consumer threads stuck on condition variable

Tags: c++, concurrency

I'm making a single producer, multiple consumers program in C++. I begin by calling consumer threads and then I add elements to an array.
Everything works fine, but in the end the consumer threads are not joining, because they're stuck waiting on condition variable and the program freezes.

I think the problem is that threads are constantly called in the loop because currentSize is not protected and they just can't exit out of the condition variable, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
struct Item {
public:
    string name;
    int time;
    double height;
};

struct Monitor {
private:
    Item items[12];
    int currentSize;
    bool finished;
    mutex lock;
    condition_variable cv;
public:
    Monitor() {
        finished = false;
        currentSize = 0;
    }
    void put(Item item) {
        unique_lock<mutex> guard(lock);
        cv.wait(guard, [&] { return (currentSize < 12); });
        items[currentSize] = item;
        currentSize++;
        cv.notify_all();
    }

    Item get() {
        unique_lock<mutex> guard(lock);
        cv.wait(guard, [&] { return (currentSize > 0); });
        Item item = items[currentSize - 1];
        currentSize--;
        return item;
    }
    bool get_finished() {
        return finished;
    }
    void set_finished() {
        finished = true;
    }
    int get_size() {
        return currentSize;
    }
};

int main() {
    vector<Item> items = read_file(file);

    Monitor monitor;
    vector<thread> threads;
    vector<Item> results;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        threads.emplace_back([&] {
            while (!monitor.get_finished()) {
                if (monitor.get_size() > 0) {
                    Item item = monitor.get();
                    results.push_back(item);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        monitor.put(items[i]);
    }
    monitor.set_finished();

    for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(), mem_fn(&thread::join));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: `results.push_back(item);` unprotected in multiple threads doesn't look all that safe.

Comment: without `Movie`, `Item`, `read_file`, it's pretty hard to repro.

Comment: At the very least, break in the debugger and provide the current location of all threads.

Comment: @Jeffrey You need to update to C++138 to get the remote telepathy support.

Comment: read_file just gets the data and Item is a struct with 3 fields. I thought it wasn't relevant so I didn't include it. Movie should be Item.

Comment: I'm only allowed 12 slots in Monitor, that's why the restriction is there. It shouldn't exceed 12 items ever, because consumers should eat them up and then producer will add them after there is enough space.

Comment: @question4567 If they aren't relevant, you remove them from the question and all of the references to them. You can; for example, `struct Item { };` to supply a dummy item since we don't care what is in it. You can replace `read_file` with `vector<Item> items = {Item(),Item(),...};` to hard code a list with however many `Item`s you want. You should also add all of the missing includes. What your goal should be is a complete-but-minimal runnable program.

Comment: All items are added to the list perfectly fine. And consumers remove them from the list too. The bug happens after producer is done and consumers aren't done yet. They get stuck waiting on condition variable in Monitor.get method and never get out.

Comment: The `notify_all` is still a problem though, and I'm sill not 100% sure who wakes up the producer.

Comment: I changed it to notify_one now. I tried that before, but it didn't help so I changed it back I guess. I also had notify_one in get method just before return statement, but I removed it while testing and forgot to add it back. It still doesn't work though.

Comment: What happens with threads that are blocked waiting on arrival of more data when `set_finished` is called? What wakes them?

Comment: Remember that you can easily have more than one bug in your software, so be careful discarding a fix that doesn't solve all of your problems.

Comment: I think that could be a problem. I don't know how to wake up these threads. But even if I did, after the array becomes empty inside the monitor and currentSize becomes 0, there are still threads waiting in the get method and even if something woke them up, they would still not execute because of predicate condition. There are just too many threads waiting there and I don't know what to do to not have them there in there in the first place.

Comment: The nasty problem is when you do figure out how to wake up, getting out of `get` without returning a garbage `Item`. You'll probably have to revise the function signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed a few issues. made the member variables atomic, notify_all in get api. However there was al logic error as well. Imagine that you have 4 threads currently running and 5 items were in queue. At this point lets say each of the thread is able to get one out of the queue and now there are 4 threads and only one item in the queue. One of the thread takes the last one out and now there is 0 items in there however other three threads still waiting on the condition variable. So a solution is if the last item is out everythread should be notified and if there is no other elemnet get back from the API.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>
#include <atomic>

using namespace std;

using Item = int;

struct Monitor {
private:
    Item items[12];
    std::atomic<int> currentSize;
    std::atomic<bool> finished;
    mutex lock;
    condition_variable cv;
public:
    Monitor() {
        finished = false;
        currentSize = 0;
    }
    void put(Item item) {
        unique_lock<mutex> guard(lock);
        cv.wait(guard, [&] { return (currentSize < 12); });
        items[currentSize] = item;
        currentSize++;
        cv.notify_all();

        std::cerr << "+ " << currentSize << std::endl ;
    }

    Item get() {
        unique_lock<mutex> guard(lock);
        cv.wait(guard, [&] { return (currentSize >= 0 ); });

        Item item;
        if (currentSize > 0 ){      
            currentSize--;
            item = items[currentSize];
            cv.notify_all();
            std::cerr << "- " << currentSize << std::endl ;
        }
        return item;
    }
    bool get_finished() {
        return finished;
    }
    void set_finished() {
        finished = true;
    }
    int get_size() {
        return currentSize;
    }
};

int main() {
    vector<Item> items(200);
    std::fill ( items.begin() , items.end(), 100);

    Monitor monitor;
    vector<thread> threads;
    vector<Item> results;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        threads.emplace_back([&] {
            while ( !monitor.get_finished() ) {
                if (monitor.get_size() > 0) {
                    Item item = monitor.get();
                    results.push_back(item);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        monitor.put(items[i]);
    }
    monitor.set_finished();

    for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(), mem_fn(&thread::join));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what the problem was, I just didn't know how to fix it.

Comment: What's the purpose of `cv.wait(guard, [&] { return (currentSize >= 0 ); });`? You never wait on this line as condition is always true.

Answer (score 3):

**Why the consumer threads block?**

I have tested your code, and it turns out to be the producer thread blocking on the `put()` method. Why?

Imagine the following scenario: there are 13 items in the vector `items`.

The main thread (producer) happily loads the first 12 items, and waits on `cv` for the `currentSize` to become lower than 12.

The consumer threads are notified, and happily consume the first 12 items, and then wait on `cv` for `currentSize` to become greater than 0.

But wait! Now everyone is waiting on something, with no one notifying. Thus, all threads would block. You need to notify the producer when `currentSize` becomes lower than 12.